# how to dispatch a <lightning-messages></lightning-messages> event and customize the message to show?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I'm using lwc's `lightning-record-edit-form` component, as we know there is a `<lightning-messages>` area to show any error while updating/inserting the record.

However I want to have a custom check the validation of the record and show the lightning-messages when the check is no-good. Is there a way to do so？

for example, if the `startDate` is later than the `endDate`, I want to show a error-message in the `<lightning-messages>` area.

Plz tell me if it's possible.

Comment: you can add a validation rule to show that, I suppose.

Comment: @NagendraSingh thank you. It works.

Comment: No problem, I have written the same as answer. Please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `validation rule` and the `lightning-message` will auto show the validation message.